# using pstack to print all threads stacktrace

Tags: linux, multithreading, pstack

I am trying to use pstack to print the stacktrace of all threads of specific process, but I get only the main thread.

According to the pstack description:
*pstack - print a stack trace of a running process

...

If the process is part of a thread group, then pstack will print out a stack trace for each of the threads in the group.*

I used gdb to attach to the process and verified that there are more threads. I run pstack with one of threads id, and got the requested result.
*[I also used ps -j and saw other **processes** with the same group id, but I don't think it is relevant]*

I read related pstack questions, but didn't see anything that can help me. Also searched google, but didn't see anyone asking about it.

Thanks

---

I didn't notice that 
"For thread information to be dumped, you have to use the debug-aware  version  of  the  LinuxThreads libpthread.so  library."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: The question was edited. Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the libpthread.so library version. According to http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html:
"For thread information to be dumped, you have to use the debug-aware version of the LinuxThreads libpthread.so library."

Since I can't replace the library, I will find the thread ids separately and use pstack on each.
Hope it will help someone.